# Crear prueba unitaria a servicios C# Net Core

Tags: c#, pruebas-unitarias, inyeccion-de-dependencias, asp.net-core-5.0, mock

Tengo una api RESTful con Net 5 y Entity Framework Core, con el patrón de diseño repository y UnitOfWork. Estoy intentando crear pruebas unitarias con MsTests para los servicios y controladores, lo he hecho según varios tutoriales pero no he logrado avanzar al crear alguna prueba.

Deseo realizarle pruebas a los métodos de actualizar, eliminar y grabar del Perfil Service.

```
Task<bool> ActualizarPerfilService(Perfiles perfil);
Task<bool> EliminarPerfilService(int idperfil, int idcliente);
Task InsertarPerfilService(Perfiles perfil);
```

La prueba que tengo actualmente sin terminar es:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using WS.Ticketing.BBDD;
using WS.Ticketing.Interfaces.Profile;

namespace PruebasUnitarias
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Perfiles perfil = new Perfiles();
            perfil.IdPerfil = 1;
            perfil.Perfil = "Puebas";
            perfil.IdCliente = 1;

            Mock<IPerfilService> perfilRepo = new Mock<IPerfilService>();
            perfilRepo.Setup(x => x.InsertarPerfilService(perfil));
            perfilRepo.Setup(x => x.ObtenerPerfilService(1)).Returns(new Perfiles() 
            {
                
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Controlador:

```
    [Authorize]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PerfilController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IPerfilService _perfilesService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public PerfilController(IPerfilService perfilesService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _perfilesService = perfilesService;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene listado de perfiles
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ObtenerPerfiles()
        {
            var perfil = await _perfilesService.ObtenerPerfilesService();

            var perfilesDto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PerfilesDto>>(perfil);

            var response = new ApiResponse<IEnumerable<PerfilesDto>>(perfilesDto);

            return Ok(response);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene perfil por id
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ObtenerPerfil(int idperfil)
        {
            var perfil = await _perfilesService.ObtenerPerfilService(idperfil);

            var perfilDto = _mapper.Map<PerfilesDto>(perfil);

            var response = new ApiResponse<PerfilesDto>(perfilDto);

            return Ok(response);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Agrega perfiles
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> InsertarPerfil(PerfilesDto perfilDto)
        {
            var perfil = _mapper.Map<Perfiles>(perfilDto);

            await _perfilesService.InsertarPerfilService(perfil);

            perfilDto = _mapper.Map<PerfilesDto>(perfil);

            var response = new ApiResponse<PerfilesDto>(perfilDto);

            return Ok(response);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene perfil por id
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ActualizarPerfil(int id, PerfilesDto perfilDto)
        {
            var perfil = _mapper.Map<Perfiles>(perfilDto);
            perfil.IdPerfil = id;

            var result = await _perfilesService.ActualizarPerfilService(perfil);

            var response = new ApiResponse<bool>(result);

            return Ok(response);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Elimina perfil por id
        /// </summary>
        [HttpDelete("{idperfil}/{idcliente}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EliminarPerfil(int idperfil, int idcliente)
        {
            var result = await _perfilesService.EliminarPerfilService(idperfil, idcliente);

            var response = new ApiResponse<bool>(result);

            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

Servicio:

```
    public class PerfilService : IPerfilService
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public PerfilService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Servicio para actualizar perfiles
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<bool> ActualizarPerfilService(Perfiles perfil)
        {
            var existeRegistro = await _unitOfWork.PerfilesRepository.GetById(perfil.IdPerfil);
            existeRegistro.Perfil = perfil.Perfil;
            existeRegistro.IdCliente = perfil.IdCliente;

            await _unitOfWork.PerfilesRepository.Update(existeRegistro);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Servicio para eliminar perfiles
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<bool> EliminarPerfilService(int idperfil, int idcliente)
        {
            await _unitOfWork.PerfilesRepository.EliminarPerfilRepository(idperfil, idcliente);

            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Servicio para grabar perfiles
        /// </summary>
        public async Task InsertarPerfilService(Perfiles perfil)
        {
            await _unitOfWork.PerfilesRepository.Add(perfil);

            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Servicio para obtener listado de perfiles
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Perfiles>> ObtenerPerfilesService()
        {
            return await _unitOfWork.PerfilesRepository.GetAll();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Servicio para obtener un perfil por id
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<Perfiles> ObtenerPerfilService(int idperfil)
        {
            return await _unitOfWork.PerfilesRepository.GetById(idperfil);
        }
    }
```

DTO:

```
public class PerfilesDto
{
    public int IdPerfil { get; set; }
    public string Perfil { get; set; }
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
}
```

Api Response:

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public ApiResponse(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public T Data { get; set; }

    public Metadata Meta { get; set; }
}
```

Service Collection Extension:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Servicios
        services.AddTransient<IPerfilService, PerfilService>();
        
        //Repositorios
        services.AddTransient<IPerfilRepository, PerfilRepository>();
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

        return services;
    }
```

Comment: y el test donde esta? y que test framework estas usando? (xUnit, Nunit, etc?)

Comment: Qué significa *. . .ninguna prueba me ha funcionado.*?

Comment: Hola @Cmbuffa ahorita agregué lo poco que llevo de la prueba. Estoy utilizando los MsTests, Gracias

Comment: Hola @Arriel el problema es que no logro avanzar al crear la prueba. Lo he intentado hacer según el tutorial https://www.netmentor.es/Entrada/mock-unit-test-csharp?fbclid=IwAR20UE8aAjtc_UtnMWm5S9MAQP1blBnxcH-xVZ8GoFBlt04v-rvnYLpADTI

Comment: Pero no hay ninguna prueba y tampoco estas específicando a que metodo del controlador quieres hacer el test, te recomiendo editar la.pregunta y agregar el framework que estas usando

Comment: @Daniel gracias, actualicé la pregunta.